# Sonar analysis & report publishing permissions

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Is it possible to restrict the publishing of new analysis on a sonar instance. My use case is I created new instance of sonar with the latest version. There are couple of projects configured with the old version. I want to make sure that no project team use old instance of sonar. At server level, is it possible to stop publishing new report.

Also what customization options sonar server gives for its home page. I want to display a custom message with Sonar 5.6 version

Atul

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have stood up two different instances of SonarQube side by side. In doing so, you impose on your teams the requirement to update their CI configuration to point to the new instance.

You should instead *replace* the old version with the new one. See [the Upgrading docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) for details.

Comment: I am using dedicated SQL database server. I cloned the existing database & attached a new cloned instance with new version of sonar. The old sonar & its database are intact, However I want teams to stop using older version. can't I stop the analysis? Also can I display some message on old sonar portal?